# Client -Server Program

Tags: java, sockets

I'm making a program of client-server using socket programing in java. I have wrriten code but when i running my code on same lappy,then it's working but when i running these codes i.e. first lappy as server and another lappy as client..then it giving me erros as follows ->

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at client.main(client.java:13)
```

And my client code --->

```
import java.net.*;  
import java.io.*;  
class client{  
public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{  
Socket ss=new Socket("10.100.90.95",8888);  
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(ss.getOutputStream());  
DataInputStream din=new DataInputStream(ss.getInputStream()); 


String str="",str2="";  
while(!str2.equals("stop")){  
str=br.readLine();  
dout.writeUTF(str);  
dout.flush();  
str2=din.readUTF();  
System.out.println("Server says: "+str2);  
}  

  }
}
```

my server code as follows -->

```
import java.net.*;  
import java.io.*;  
class server{  
public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{  
ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(3333);  
Socket s=ss.accept();  
DataInputStream din=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());  
DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());  
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));  

String str="",str2="";  
while(!str.equals("stop")){  
str=din.readUTF();  
System.out.println("client says: "+str);  
str2=br.readLine();  
dout.writeUTF(str2);  
dout.flush();  
}  
din.close();  
s.close();  
ss.close();  
}}
```

So Please tell me,what's wrong with this.
Thnaku.

Comment: Because of dynamic IP assignment and network router firewall issues, it can be very difficult to do what you are trying to do

Comment: You use different ports for client and server?

Comment: it looks like different port no. uses, maintain it common like either 8888 or 3333

Comment: Sorry  Guys , It was typing mistake. In actual program i am using same port number but it still not working.   It is showing the above exception, so please tell me how to handle this exception.

Answer (score 1):

You're listening on 3333 but trying to connect to 8888. It doesn't make sense. You need to listen on the same port number you're trying to connect to.

Comment: Sorry, I typed  here by mistake . In actual program i'm using same port number.